# What happens when I drop a column in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance

If my understanding is right then the number of rows that are stored on one page in SQL Server is determined by the number of columns in the table and their datatypes. One I/O operation can read one page, so the more rows fits into one page, the more rows can be returned by one I/O operation, and your queries run faster.

I wonder what happens when you drop a column? Does SQL Server go back to the memory and "re-stores" the data, i.e what if I drop enough columns for more data to fit on one page? And if SQL Server does not do that automatically, can I force the process?

I'm removing a lot of text columns and a few IDs on the heavily used table, and I hoping that the I/O will improve after I drop the columns.

Comment: It's not that simple. Raw I/O is only important when you're doing full scans, I imagine. Most of the time you should be using indexes. Also, sql server should have commands for compacting the data files.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev thanks a lot for your reply. Just from experience, the narrow tables work much faster comparing to the wide tables. The I/O cost is much smaller for the narrow tables (according to the execution plans). So I'm just trying to find out if there any additional steps that I can take to make sure I get most gains our of the columns deletion

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Dropping a column is a logical operation, not physical. No data gets modified. The column metadata gets marked as 'deleted' and will be ignored. The record size is unchanged. Read [SQL Server table columns under the hood](http://rusanu.com/2011/10/20/sql-server-table-columns-under-the-hood/) for more details explanation and clear examples demonstrating my claim.

As Stefan said, you have to rebuild the table (heap or clustered index) to 'reclaim' the space.

> I'm removing a lot of text columns and a few IDs on the heavily used table, and I hoping that the I/O will improve after I drop the columns.

Use indexes to reduce IO. For unindexable ad-hoc analytical workloads, use columnstores. Read [How to analyse SQL Server performance](http://rusanu.com/2014/02/24/how-to-analyse-sql-server-performance/).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. Unfortunately I don't always know the queries used, because we have Business Objects generating the queries. So I can't use indexes all the time.

Answer (score 5):

You can rebuild the clustered index to force SQL Server use the free space. Otherwise you have "holes" in the pages.

Comment: I'm gonna mark the Remus's reply as the answer because it provides more info that could be helpful to other people. But thank you very much for your help. Really appreciate it